# how can plot the safest route in a graph using bfs and a route table in java

Tags: java, algorithm, search, path, routes

I have a graph of nodes which contain resource levels and they can be positive and negative, the principle is a lady bird or some object gets life from each node or gets hurt by a node.

Ive managed to implement the BFS with a queue structure:-

given a graph with no node resources

```
  a---b---e
  |       |
  c---d   f
```

the route table is :-

```
node    parent
===============
a       null
b       a
c       a
d       c
e       b
f       e
```

so the route is plotted using the parent, assuming that (a) is the starting node and (f) is the exit node
the quickest route is from the bottom f-e-b-a

Ive solved this in java code the problem is how do you use this method with each node having resources that can kill you or give you life.

so say some nodes have -20 and others give +10

Im not sure how to determine the route given the queue structure ive used.

Does anyone have any ideas?

I dont need the java code necessarily however anything will help, Im really interested in the theory of a solution and what data structure could be used etc...

my idea is maybe

```
child  parent  resource
=======================
a       b       20+
b       a       10-
c       b       5+
```

the thing is im not sure how to store the different routes, this table only stores one route.

Answer (score 0):

BFS isn't really used for finding shortest paths when all edge lengths aren't the same.  I would suggest the [Bellman Ford Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman-Ford_algorithm).  Like Dijkstra's algorithm, it is used to compute shortest paths given a graph.  However, unlike Dijkstra's algorithm it allows you to operate on graphs where not all edge lengths are positive (which it appears you will have given your question).

Here's a [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ttezuzs39nk) explaining it (via OpenCourseWare).

Comment: That is really useful, I will take a looking into this algorithm, I know of Dijkstra's but as you said it doesn't deal with negative weights